# What's the difference between Supervision.Restart and Supervision.Resume really?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

what's the difference between `Supervision.Restart` and `Supervision.Resume` really ?

Here is the situation. I have 3 elements coming from the `Source(List(1, 2, 3))`. In `runForeach` I throw exception if element is `2`. For `Supervision.Restart` I expected only `1` to be processed. But oddly I see `3` reaching sink. Why ? I'm using Akka 2.4.11

```
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, ActorMaterializerSettings, OverflowStrategy, Supervision}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source

val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
  case _: NotImplementedError =>
    Supervision.Restart
  case _                      =>
    Supervision.Stop
}

implicit val system = ActorSystem("root")
implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(system).withSupervisionStrategy(decider))(system)

Source(List(1, 2, 3))
  .map { v =>
    if (v == 2)
      throw new NotImplementedError
    v
  }
  .runForeach(println)
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/HSj01pO/3

Answer (score 2):

In your example your `Flow` is (also called `FlowShape`):

```
.map { v =>
  if (v == 2)
    throw new NotImplementedError
  v
}
```

The main difference is:

- `Supervision.Restart`: a new instance of your actor will be created which will have the initial state of your class. The previous state will be lost. In your case it will be the state of your `Flow`.
- `Supervision.Resume`: the same instance is reused with the previous state. In your case it will be the state of your `Flow`.

In your case, your `Flow` is stateless so there is no difference between `Supervision.Restart` and `Supervision.Resume`.

Since you have `case _: NotImplementedError => Supervision.Restart`, then `1` gets `map`ped and reaches the `Sink`. `2` throws a `NotImplementedError` which restarts your `Flow`, drops that message but does not stop your stream. And then `3` gets `map`ped and reaches the `Sink`. Therefore you should see in the output `1` and `3`.

Comment: Is there way to flush buffer on failure ? Otherwise I don't see difference in these two handlers. Because I don't use actor here directly I guess all streams are always stateless.

Comment: Well, in your example you are only going through a `List(1, 2, 3)` and you could directly stop the stream. However, in a more real-time scenario where your stream is listening for messages, in case you get a bad message you might just want to drop that one bad message and keep your stream running for new incoming messages. That you can do with `restart` or `resume`. The `akka-streams` apis does not give you access to actors directly, however it creates actors internally that actually perform the operations `map`, `filter`, etc... which is why I mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: Also, it is perfectly possible to have a stateful `Flow` in you define your `Flow` in a separate class that contains state. Please check this for more reference: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html