# why akka-stream restart supervision doesn't restart but just resume

Tags: akka-stream, akka-supervision

Consider this simple stream:

```
Source(1 to 5)
.mapAsync(1) { i =>
  if (i % 3 == 0) Future.failed(new Exception("I don't like 3"))
  else Future.successful(i)
}
.withAttributes(
  ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(Supervision.restartingDecider)
)
.runForeach(i => println(s"#$i"))
```

This actually prints

```
#1
#2
#4
```

Which is the same as with the resume strategy.
I would expect the stream to restart after the failed future with the following output

```
#1
#2
#1
#2
...
```

1. Why does the Resume and Restart strategy behaves the same way in this case?
2. How can I restart the stream from start?

Comment: I had related question :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/39822628/226895 Please post here if you find answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**: the difference between `resume` and `restart` is that - with the latter - the failing stage is restarted, losing all accumulated internal state. (See [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/scala/stream/stream-error.html#Supervision_Strategies) for reference).

In your case, you have a `mapAsync` stage with parallelism 1, so you effectively will never have any accumulated state. This results in `resume` and `restart` being equivalent in behaviour.

**Question 2:** The semantic of supervision strategies in Akka streams are related to the specific stage that fails. A failed stage simply has no way to replay the elements that flowed in the past, as they are already gone - i.e. not held anywhere. No supervision strategy can give you that.

What you are looking for is a restart *of the whole stream* which should be achievable with the `recoverWithRetries` combinator ([docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#recoverWithRetries)). You can feed the same source again (`Source(1 to 5)`) to the combinator to have it replay those elements.